# select with multiple join and conditions where column null codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking to get items from database where the items has options and some not.

My model to get the data is: {This return only products that product.id is in options and option_values}

```
$category_id = 2;
$this->db->select('category_products.*, products.*, option_values.price as prodPrice, option_values.special_price, LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(option_values.special_price, 0), option_values.price), option_values.price) as sort_price', false)
         ->from('category_products')
         ->join('products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id')
         ->join('options', 'options.product_id=attributes.product_id')
         ->join('option_values', 'option_values.option_id=options.id')
         ->where('category_products.category_id', $category_id)
         ->where('option_values.inventory >', '0');
         ->where('products.quantity >', '0');
$this->db->group_by('products.id');

$result = $this->db->get()->result();
return $result;
```

But i need to get also items that has no options and options_values.

category_products table:

```
product_id | category_id | sequence
74 | 2 | 0
75 | 2 | 0
```

products table:

```
id | code | name | type | price | saleprice | quantity
74 | 12345_ | Product with options | 1 | 0 | NULL | 1
75 | 12346_ | Product without options | 2 | 199 | NULL | 1
```

options table:

```
id | product_id | sequence | name | type | required
74 | 74 | 1 | Size | radiolist | 1
```

option_values table:

```
id | option_id | name | value | price | special_price | weight | inventory | sequence | limit
777 | 74 | 8K | 12345 | 199.00 | 159.00 | 1.00 | 0 | 17 | NUL
```

With the model i write above i can get only the product_id 74, and my question is how can i adapt the query to get the product_id 75 to?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do left join instead of inner join.`->join('products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id',"left")`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your joins to include `LEFT JOIN`.  I don't have a database set up so I can't test it but I would try the following:

**NOTE**: the addition of the `left` parameters in the `join()` functions.

```
$category_id = 2;
            $this->db->select('category_products.*, products.*, option_values.price as prodPrice, option_values.special_price, LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(option_values.special_price, 0), option_values.price), option_values.price) as sort_price', false)
                    ->from('category_products')
                    ->join('products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id', 'left')
                    ->join('options', 'options.product_id=attributes.product_id', 'left')
                    ->join('option_values', 'option_values.option_id=options.id', 'left')
                    ->where('category_products.category_id', $category_id)
                    ->where('option_values.inventory >', '0');
                    ->where('products.quantity >', '0');
            $this->db->group_by('products.id');

            $result = $this->db->get()->result();

            return $result;
```

You might need to modify the joins to be `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins to get the desired result.  I may try to simulate it a little later when I get a minute.

This is a [good article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) on understanding MySQL joins.  I refer to it from time to time when I have to craft complex queries.

Comment: Yes, with Left join works only i remove ->where('option_values.inventory >', '0'); because for the product that has no option_values on column inventory is null.